# What's the right way to insert/update multiple rows in MySQL? Am I doing it right?

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I have a database that looks something like this:

```
id | product_id | tag
------------------------
1  | 10000      | tag1
------------------------
2  | 10000      | tag2 
------------------------
3  | 10000      | tag3
------------------------
4  | 10001      | tag2 
------------------------
5  | 10002      | tag1
------------------------
6  | 10002      | tag2
```

Every day we check a web service for an updated list of tags and then update the database. The database contains 50,000 products, so we only check for perhaps a 100 products at a time.

Currently, when I check each product (e.g. product_id 10000), I will simply delete all rows (DELETE FROM table WHERE product_id = 10000)
and then insert all tags, one by one.

I'm wondering if there is a better way for me to do this (I'm thinking about something similar to the "INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..." I use when it's a single row I'm inserting/updating. My initial thought was to just insert them, but if I do that, the database won't know if a tag has been deleted)

What I'm doing now works fine, but this sort of stuff comes up all the time and it seems like there should be a better way to do this, one that doesn't have as many calls to the database.

Comment: Are you aware you can insert multiple rows with one INSERT statement?

Comment: Where is your new data coming from? Another DB or files?

Comment: @BillKarwin Yes, I am aware, but honestly I don't do that very often, I've thought about it, but never done it. Is that "better"?

Comment: @fifonik No, a REST web service, where I can only ask for information about one product at a time.

Comment: Meaning that you get 3 tags all at once for id 10000?  As well as inserting new tags, do you also need to delete any tags that don't show up in the REST response?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not doing delete/insert for tags that have not changed as:

- IDs will change (that might be critical sometimes)
- it might be triggers that will be executed with no reason

Sure, in some cases delete/insert is perfectly fine, but this is my general rule: do not modify unchanged data.

So my approach in this case would be:

```
DELETE FROM
    tags
WHERE
    product_id = 10000
    AND tag NOT IN ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3')
;

INSERT (...) VALUES (...), (...), ... ON DUPLICATE KEYS UPDATE ...
```

Comment: good point, probably wont matter in my example, but still a good point!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using transactions to do that, you're good to go.

The only issue I able to think of that strategy is if the DB shutdown in the middle of operations, but transactions solves that.

Comment: Only partially.  The receipt of the REST message is not part of the transaction.  But, in this app, rerunning the code for a given productid will always(?) be 'safe'.